# The disk hosting is full this may be the cause of the following Exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel Framework version 5.3.31
The login page is not working any more giving error 
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:

And mobile apps linked to web services using laravel api routes is not working.
I tried to figure out what is the problem 
When i run composer dump-autoload the following error show:

```
Cannot create cache directory /var/www/tdsteam/.cache/composer/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /var/www/tdsteam/.cache/composer/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
PHP temp directory (/tmp) does not exist or is not writable to Composer. Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini
Generating autoload files
The disk hosting /var/www/tdsteam/nfb/vendor is full, this may be the cause of the following exception


  [ErrorException]
  file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 1153 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space
```

I also founded the following error in laravel.log file:

```
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/tdstea...', 111, Array)
#1 /var/www/tdsteam/nfb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php(111): file_put_contents('/var/www/tdstea...', '1511464592i:1;', 2)
#2 /var/www/tdsteam/nfb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php(107): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->put('/var/www/tdstea...', '1511464592i:1;', true)
#3 /var/www/tdsteam/nfb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(206): Illuminate\Cache\FileStore->put('b478d193a7a9f6f...', '1511464592i:1;', '1')
#4 /var/www/tdsteam/nfb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(253): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->put('b478d193a7a9f6f...', 1, '1')
#5 /var/www/tdsteam/nfb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php(62): Illuminate\Cache\Repository->add('b478d193a7a9f6f...', 1, '1')
#6 /var/www/tdsteam/nfb/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(47): Illuminate\root@server3:/var/www/tdsteam/nfb/storage/logs#
```

How to solve this issue , and why this issue happened?

The last thing i did but not sure if this caused the issue or not 
I changed the FTP password then,
In PhpStorm > New Project From Existing Files > Web server is on remote host, files are accessible via FTP/SFTP > I entered the FTP info > Then it starting downloading the project files.

I observed also that the public and some folder permission is changed when Phpstorm start downloading them :
The default /public folder permission is : drwxr-xr-x
The Phpstorm changed /public permission to : drwxrwxrwx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the system disk is full

```
/dev/root        20G   19G     0 100% /
```

Comment: That'll do it... (and Composer *did* try to tell you this...)